# How to show a dialog in web view when long click on links

Tags: android, webview

I have a web view that I want to make a dialog, When user long click on links. Like Google Chrome app:

[image: Google Chrome ScreenShot]

So, I write this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(@NonNull ContextMenu menu, @NonNull View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    final WebView.HitTestResult result = webView.getHitTestResult();
    menu.setHeaderTitle(result.getExtra());
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Open In New Tab");

}
```

And This is the result of code in **Yahoo** search engine:

[image: Yahoo ScreenShot]

Everything all right And I can open a new tab with URL that has in the header Title, But when I used **Google** search engine, *result.getExtra()* returned a base64 String:

[image: Google ScreenShot]

How I can get a URL from the **Google** search engine to create a new tab?

Comment: You Should use Handler for it, Check this solution:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61521659/11270934)